# Build.Gradle Templating

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, modularization

Does anyone know of a way to template build.gradle files as modules are created? Right now the issue I have is that I want to be able to have the module's build.gradle contain only a small amount of information since I'd be setting the shared configuration within the top level build.gradle file. I have a buildSrc folder setup to centralize the versioning as well.

Top-level build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath Deps.tools_gradleandroid
        classpath Deps.tools_kotlin
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10'
    }
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
            android {
                buildToolsVersion Config.buildTools
                compileSdkVersion Config.compileSdk

                defaultConfig {
                    minSdkVersion Config.minSdk
                    targetSdkVersion Config.targetSdk
                    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                }

                buildTypes {
                    release {
                        minifyEnabled false
                        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                    }
                }

                compileOptions {
                    sourceCompatibility Config.javaVersion
                    targetCompatibility Config.javaVersion
                }

                kotlinOptions {
                    jvmTarget = Config.javaVersion.toString()
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

A module's expected build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.expectedmodule"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation Deps.androidx_core
    implementation Deps.androidx_appcompat
    implementation Deps.androidx_material
    testImplementation Deps.testlib_junit
    androidTestImplementation Deps.testandroidx_junit
    androidTestImplementation Deps.testandroidx_espressocore
}
```

What the build.gradle file looks like when I create a 'New Module':

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.newmodule"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

EDIT: For sake of simplicity I've moved the dependencies bracket to the top-level build.gradle file and also changed the modules to be libraries instead and reduced the code of a library module to below:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

recommended way of sharing build logic in Gradle is by using convention plugins. Like in this [sample](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html).

Also [precompiled script plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins) can be used to write plugins in syntax similar to regular build scripts.